# C++ Exception testing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, exception

I want to test what exception was returned. In all examples on exception handling I see they are just printing some message, no real test on the type of exception. So I tried this:

```
string Out_of_range{ "stol argument out of range" };
long Long;
try{
    Long = stol( "12345678901234567890" );

} catch( exception& Ex ){
    string What = Ex.what();
    if( What == Out_of_range )
        cout << "OK 1\n";;
    if( Ex.what() == What )
        cout << "OK 2\n";;
    if( Ex.what() == Out_of_range )
        cout << "OK 3\n";;
    if( Ex.what() == "stol argument out of range" )
        cout << "OK 4\n";;
}
```

and the result is

```
OK 1
OK 2
OK 3
```

Question 1: why is the fourth if statement false?

Question 2: is there another way to test an exception than using the what member?

Comment: _"is there another way to test an exception than using the what member?"_ Yes. Use multiple `catch()` blocks, one for each particular exception type. Also catch exceptions by `const` reference.

Comment: Also note that the signature of `std::exception::what()` is `const char* what() const;`. It's pretty unlikely that the string literal and the result of `what()` are pointing to the same memory address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Question 1: why is the fourth if statement false?"*

The signature of [`std::exception::what()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) is

```
virtual const char* what() const;
```

It's pretty unlikely that the string literal and the result of `what()` are pointing to the same memory address which are compared in your case.

> *"Question 2: is there another way to test an exception than using the what member?"*

Yes. Use multiple `catch() {}` blocks, one for each particular exception type. Also you should `catch()` exceptions by `const` reference:

```
try{
    Long = stol( "12345678901234567890" );

} catch(const std::invalid_argument& Ex) {
    // Handle invalid_argument exception
} catch(const std::out_of_range& Ex) {
    // Handle out_of_range exception
} catch( ... )
    // Handle unexpected exception
}
```

Comment: I'm coming from Perl and had to switch to C++ because of performance issues with a heavy computational program. So I'm used to the simpleness of types and where a string is a string, everywhere. In C++ I keep hurting myself that there are strings, and strings that look completely the same but are totally different. What a mess!

Comment: @JanLaloux C++ usually enforces usage of `std::string` rather than `char*`. `std::exception::what()` is one of the rare exceptions (no pun intended).

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1: why is the fourth if statement false?

In that line you are comparing two `char const*`, not two strings.

> Question 2: is there another way to test an exception than using the what member?

`std::stol` can throw the following exceptions (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

- `std::invalid_argument` if no conversion could be performed
- `std::out_of_range` if the converted value would fall out of the range of the result type or if the underlying function (`std::strtol` or `std::strtoll`) sets `errno` to `ERANGE`.

You can use explicit `catch` blocks for those two types of exceptions.

```
try
{
   Long = stol( "12345678901234567890" );
}
catch( std::invalid_argument const& Ex )
{
   // Deal with the exception
}
catch( std::out_of_range const& Ex )
{
   // Deal with the exception
}
catch( exception const& Ex )
{
   // Deal with the exception
}
```

Comment: Little nitpick: Exceptions should be caught by `const` reference or value.

Comment: I agree with the `const` part but not by the value part. If you catch by value, you take the risk of getting your objects sliced.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the value part, this could easily happen.